# Open cir sp sim with spice syntax

Tags: vim, vi

**Problem statement:**
When I open a file with .sp extention with vim it opens with spice syntax which the same file with .sim/.cir extension does not open with spice syntax.

**My efforts:**
I tried by added the below line in .vimrc but it's not working.

`au BufRead *.sim setfiletype spice`

**Details:**
I have the following lines in .vimrc

`syntax on`

`filetype on`

**Looking for:** I am looking for an option that we can add in .vimrc to enable a set of file extensions(sim/cir/sp) to open with a spice syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't already exist, create the following directory:

```
~/.vim/ftdetect
```

Then create `~/.vim/ftdetect/spice.vim` (the filename doesn't have to be `spice.vim`) with the following content:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.sim,*.cir set filetype=spice
```

See `:help new-filetype`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you.